# How to reproject a layer?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm using [Highmaps](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo) as a visualization map tool in my system. With Highmaps, among the [official Highmaps maps](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/), I can use custom geojsons maps. I am trying to use this one as a custom geojson: https://github.com/fititnt/gis-dataset-brasil/blob/master/mesorregiao/geojson/mesorregiao.json

The problem is, to use a custom geojson, Highmaps needs us to define an object on the geojson to tell which projection that geojson is in, as stated on the [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/latlon). Since it is a map from Brazil, I though using the same projection as the official map from Brazil provided by Highmaps. But it doesn't work. When I try to plot a lat/long point, it plots on the wrong place.

Investigating why this would happen, I opened both geojsons in QGIS and found out that they seem to be in different projections:

[image: qgis]

(The small dot is also a brazil map)

Then I checked the attributes for each layer and found out the following:

- **brazil1**
- CRS: `EPSG:29101 - SAD69 / Brazil Polyconic - Projected`
- Extent: `-999.0000000000000000,-979.0000000000000000 : 9851.0000000000000000,9851.0000000000000000`
- **mesorregiao**
- CRS: `EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic`
- Extent: `-73.9902501510268849,-33.7515827781719508 : -28.8356556089732976,5.2721557581718343`

Then I tried to use the `Reproject Layer` tool on the `mesorregiao` layer to reproject it to `SAD69`, as the `brazil1` layer but it just created another layer in the same position as the `mesorregiao` was before.

So my question is: **How can I reproject/transform the `mesorregiao` layer in order for it to overlay the `brazil1` layer and so I can use it with Highmaps?**

Comment: The brazil1 data's extent does NOT match 29101 extent. It should be more like: 2760000,6188000 to 7200000,10600000 (very roughly). The highmaps almost looks like it's not georeferenced. They may be doing some internal thing.

Comment: Hi mkennedy, thanks for the reply. Yes, I also think this may be the case. But still, I do believe that if I can get `mesorregiao` to overlay the highmaps one, it should work. Do you know if there is a way of doing that?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your issue. I will remove answer. Typically, you should be able to reproject with QGIS, but it looks like the json file from highmaps has some offets off the ESPG29101.